# ABaddressbook use kABPersonCreationDateProperty as Verification if RecordID is different

Tags: ios, objective-c, abaddressbook

As I am researching on the solution for the uniqueID of contacts record that will change as this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14763688/keeping-a-long-term-reference-to-an-ios-addressbook-entry#new-answer), I am wondering , will it be a good idea if we use Record Creation date , as a "confirm flag " , if the Record having same Name and same creation date , my app will treat it as same contact and update the record ID, and if it is different, it would probably a different contact , Which User create it in different time, either on purpose or on accidentally manually duplicate.

In my opinion , user can hardly create 2 contact with the same Creation date time, which i think it could be a good flag for verification.

Is there any chances that a contact creation date can change after the creation ?