# Match AddressBook Records from IOS & OS X?

Tags: ios, macos, addressbook, abperson

Is there a way to match a unique identifier from a ABPerson record on OS X to one on IOS ? At first glance I cannot get the same id from the same person on my address book.
For starters, on the mac the property kABUIDProperty is of type string, and on iOS there is the ABRecordID which is an integer type.

So my question is, how can I retrieve the same ABPerson record on IOS & OS X, considering that both devices are synced vía iCloud.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem, so I've decided to gather all the information on topic.

From the Address Book Programming Guide (iOS)

> Every record in the Address Book database has a unique record
>   identifier. This identifier always refers to the same record, unless
>   that record is deleted or the data is reset. Record identifiers can be
>   safely passed between threads. **They are not guaranteed to remain the
>   same across devices**

From the Address Book Programming Guide (OSX)

> Each group and person has a unique identifier. It’s set when the
>   record is created, and **guaranteed never to change** even if a user
>   changes the group’s or person’s name or other information. Use this
>   identifier if your application needs to store a reference to a group
>   or person. For more information, see the ABRecord method uniqueId.

But appears that in reality it does change for example when user turns off/on iCloud :

http://mjtsai.com/blog/2011/11/07/kabuidproperty/

So the best way to do this is :

> The recommended way to keep a long-term reference to a particular
>   record is to store the first and last name, or a hash of the first and
>   last name, in addition to the identifier. When you look up a record by
>   ID, compare the record’s name to your stored name. If they don’t
>   match, use the stored name to find the record, and store the new ID
>   for the record.

also worth reading:
[Keeping a long-term reference to an IOS AddressBook entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14763688/keeping-a-long-term-reference-to-an-ios-addressbook-entry)

Regarding the new Contacts Framework :

**CNContact.identifier**

> It is recommended that you use the identifier when re-fetching the
>   contact. An identifier can be persisted between the app launches. Note
>   that this identifier **only uniquely identifies the contact on the
>   current device**.