# Unique reference to a Record in ABAddressBook

Tags: ios, objective-c, icloud, abaddressbook

I was working with *AddressBook Framework*. The requirement is to save some contacts selected from *AddressBook* and the saved contacts will be edited some later times. So I used **ABRecordGetRecordID(ABRecordRef record)** method to get the unique identifier to the AddressBook record. Complete code is added below.

```
ABAddressBookRef addressBook  = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, error);
CFArrayRef allPeople          = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);

// Started looping in allPeople... loopCount=> looping variable

ABRecordRef person            = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(allPeople, loopCount)
// Fetching the unique id to the contact 
CFIndex uniqueId              = ABRecordGetRecordID(person);
```

And the issue is, this `uniqueId` is changed after I synced my contacts with **iCloud**.

Is that a bug in the implementation of *iOS AddressBook* of do i need to update something in my code ???

or

Please refer me some other idea to uniquely identify an individual contact record in *AddressBook* iOS.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a long term persistent unique ID! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14763688/keeping-a-long-term-reference-to-an-ios-addressbook-entry