# Is ABRecord.uniqueId consistent across devices?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode10

In API version xcode10.x, is [ABRecord#uniqueId](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/addressbook/abrecord/1400515-uniqueid?changes=latest_minor) finally consistent across devices?

The [now-archived documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/Chapters/DirectInteraction.html) says that the record ID is not guaranteed to stay consistent across devices but the current documentation is a bit fuzzy — there is no mention of whether [ABRecord#uniqueId](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14763688/keeping-a-long-term-reference-to-an-ios-addressbook-entry?rq=1) is consistent across devices despite an explicit note that [CNContact#identifier](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/contacts/cncontact/1403103-identifier) should only be used on the current device.

Worst case I can assume that the `recordId` is still prone to change and implement the suggested strategy in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14816704/2213364) but it would be nice if Apple has finally decided to expose the identifier that they use to keep contacts in sync.

Comment: Curious why the downvote? I know this is a common question and looks like a dupe but all of the questions on SO appear to be referencing older APIs.